# Populate listview from access database using another listview in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, listview

I have two listviews, `lvNum` having one column and `lvList` have 8 columns. I want to populate my `lvList` from my access database through my `lvNum` . If I click a row in my `lvNum`, my `lvList` items will be added from the database. If I click once the `lvList` is populated,but when I click another cell it gives me an error

> InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

This is my code to load the record to all my listviews

```
 Public Sub loadRecord(lv As ListView, sql As String, noOfIndex As Integer)
    Try
        lv.Items.Clear()
        Dim lvcmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, konek)
        Dim lvdr As OleDbDataReader = lvcmd.ExecuteReader

        If lvdr.HasRows Then
            While lvdr.Read
                Dim newLv As New ListViewItem
                newLv.Text = lvdr.GetValue(0)
                For item As Integer = 1 To noOfIndex
                    newLv.SubItems.Add(lvdr.GetValue(item))
                Next
                lv.Items.Add(newLv)
            End While
        End If           
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Load Record Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I call the sub in the lvNum selectedIndexChanged event

```
Private Sub lvNum_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvNum.SelectedIndexChanged
 'this is where I get my error
    Dim joindRecord As String = "SELECT tblProducts.prodName,tblProducts.prodCode,tblProducts.Description," & _
        "tblProducts.prodCost,tblPurchaseOrder.POQty,tblPurchaseOrder.PODiscount, tblPurchaseOrder.total," & _
        "tblPurchaseOrder.prodID,tblProducts.prodID,tblPurchaseOrder.PONumber " & _
        "FROM tblProducts INNER JOIN tblPurchaseOrder ON tblProducts.prodID = tblPurchaseOrder.prodID " & _
        "WHERE tblPurchaseOrder.PONumber ='" & lvNum.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text & "'"

    Call loadRecord(lvList, joindRecord, 7)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I added this piece of code

```
If lvPO.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then 
 'code goes here
End If
```

So the code goes like this

```
Private Sub lvNum_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  Handles lvNum.SelectedIndexChanged
If lvPO.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
   Dim joindRecord As String = "SELECT  tblProducts.prodName,tblProducts.prodCode,tblProducts.Description," & _
    "tblProducts.prodCost,tblPurchaseOrder.POQty,tblPurchaseOrder.PODiscount, tblPurchaseOrder.total," & _
    "tblPurchaseOrder.prodID,tblProducts.prodID,tblPurchaseOrder.PONumber " & _
    "FROM tblProducts INNER JOIN tblPurchaseOrder ON tblProducts.prodID = tblPurchaseOrder.prodID " & _
    "WHERE tblPurchaseOrder.PONumber ='" & lvNum.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text & "'"

   Call loadRecord(lvList, joindRecord, 7)
End If
End Sub
```